# Convert dict with lists of items to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dictionary:

```
print(d)

{1: ([4, 3, 2], [10.0, 6.666666666666667, 7.5]),
 2: ([4, 3, 2], [6.0, 6.666666666666667, 8.5]),
 3: ([4, 3, 2], [26.0, 29.666666666666668, 7.5])}
```

I want to convert into a pandas df. I would also like to specify the column names. Col1 should be the key of the dictionary.
Output should look like this (rounding not required):

```
col1  col2  col3  
 1     4     10
 1     3     6.6
 1     2     7.5
 2     4     6
 2     3     6.6
 2     2     8.5
 3     4     26
 3     3     29.6
 3     2     7.5
```

I tried this:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

But that results in a df with lists as column values

```
    0                                       1
1   [4, 3, 2]   [10.0, 6.666666666666667, 7.5]
2   [4, 3, 2]   [6.0, 6.666666666666667, 8.5]
3   [4, 3, 2]   [26.0, 29.666666666666668, 7.5]
4   [4, 3, 2]   [5.25, 5.333333333333333, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can flatten the dictionary to create the triplets representing rows of dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(k, *t) for k, v in d.items() for t in zip(*v)])
```

---

```
   0  1          2
0  1  4  10.000000
1  1  3   6.666667
2  1  2   7.500000
3  2  4   6.000000
4  2  3   6.666667
5  2  2   8.500000
6  3  4  26.000000
7  3  3  29.666667
8  3  2   7.500000
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to `explode` the dataframe -

```
df  = pd.DataFrame(d).T.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
```

**Output -**

```
   index  0          1
0      1  4       10.0
1      1  3   6.666667
2      1  2        7.5
3      2  4        6.0
4      2  3   6.666667
5      2  2        8.5
6      3  4       26.0
7      3  3  29.666667
8      3  2        7.5
```

Then to rename columns use->

```
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can "explode" both lists at once by concatenating them and using `pd.Series`

```
d = {1: ([4, 3, 2], [10.0, 6.666666666666667, 7.5]),
 2: ([4, 3, 2], [6.0, 6.666666666666667, 8.5]),
 3: ([4, 3, 2], [26.0, 29.666666666666668, 7.5])}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')

df.apply(lambda r: pd.Series(np.concatenate(list(r)), index=np.repeat(r.index,len(r))))
```

|  | 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 10 |
| 1 | 3 | 6.66667 |
| 1 | 2 | 7.5 |
| 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 | 6.66667 |
| 2 | 2 | 8.5 |
| 3 | 4 | 26 |
| 3 | 3 | 29.6667 |
| 3 | 2 | 7.5 |